# Java Canvas scale to window

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I want my canvas to have a fixed width and high so when say item 200px, by 100px that is relative to the canvas but may get display bigger or smaller depending on the user screen size. So what it want to know is can make canvas 640x360 or what ever size i want but display it the bigger i can on the users screen as zoom so all distastes are the same.

Comment: Canvas, I'm guessing you're just using a JPanel, not canvas from JavaFX? Do you wish to maintain aspect ratio if user stretches window to different shape than original?

Comment: This would be easily achieved by applying a scale instance of an `AffineTransform` to the `Graphics2D` object. Even simpler, [`Graphics2D.scale(sx,sy)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale-double-double-)..

Comment: I mean the swing canvas, from java just inside JFrame, does it need to be in JPanel to scale? yes i want the keep aspect ratio, it should be a zoom, if a user has screen of twice it show 4 pixel for each on i the canvas.

Comment: *"I mean the swing canvas"* There's **no such thing** as a `javax.swing.Canvas`. If you don't even know what classes/packages are involved, how are we supposed to help? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).